# Отключить mod_rewrite для папки

Tags: админка, .htaccess, php

Привет всем. Искал в гугле ответ на свой вопрос, но все ответы мне не подошли, сколько я ни пытался...

Итак, в корне сайте есть .htaccess, которые перенаправляет все запросы на index.php простым решением:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php [L,NS]
```

Дело в том, что на сайте существует и папка admin со своим index.php. Все нормально работает, но при попытке запаролировать эту папку ( .htpaswd), ничего не выходит - запрос идет через главный index.php, а там Контроллер НЕ НАХОДИТ метод admin и перенаправляет на страницу "404 not found". Как мне прописать mod_rewrite так, чтобы index.php из папки admin( да и вся папка) НЕ попадала под редирект????

Сайт находится на сервере под Linux. Папка admin имеет права доступа 755

UPDATE. В папке admin содержится htaccess со следующим кодом:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Restricted Access"
AuthUserFile path_to_dir/admin/.htpasswd
Require user dddddddd
```

**UPDATE2** И вообще каким это образом, htaccess с установкой пароля из папки admin влияет на то, что ВНЕЗАПНО основной роутер начинает вести себя подобным образом и выводить 404? Убираю этот htaccess - и папка нормально начинает открываться!

**UPDATE3** Вопрос, по видимому уже устарел, но - может кто-то еще прочитает. Дело в том, что mysite/admin имеет свой index.php, и главный роутер вообще про него ничего не знает, т.е. папка admin живет своей жизнью...

Comment: Попробуйте самым первым правилом для редиректа прописать условия для admin/index.php

Comment: @terantul, даже не представляю, как это сделать. Не подскажите? Я перебрал столько вариантов...

Comment: RewriteRule ^admin/(.*?)/?$ admin/index.php$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ index.php$1 [L]
При чтении правил выполняется первое же соответствующее. В Ваше случае все запросы к admin будут переадресовываться на индексный файл админки, остальные все попадут на стандартную страницу.
как то так. 
Тут есть более подробное описание возможностей:
http://www.shtogrin.com/library/web/mod_rewrite/doc/RewriteCond/

Comment: @terantul, спасибо, но ничего  не получается. Пробовал менять в вашей строчке любые варианты. Не катит.

Comment: Первым кондом:  

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/?admin/

Comment: @ReinRaus, опять не вышло. Я не пойму в чем дело. Если я из папки admin убираю htaccess (с паролями), то эта папка прекрасно открывается, но только я ставлю пароль - запрос опять начинает идти через основной роутер и - "страницы не существует"...

Comment: @ReinRaus кондом это 5!

Comment: @terantul, на ваш вопрос я отвечаю: использую ЧПУ

Answer (score 2):

Если Ваш приведённый скрипт лежит в корне, а admin это каталог который там же находится, то в admin достаточно добавить пустой .htaccess файл. И тогда он перетрет правила корневого. По умолчанию файл распространяется на ту директорию в которой лежит и на все дочерние.

Comment: Я не могу его оставить пустым, в htaccess прописывается, что папка запаролена!

Comment: @Deus ну так пишите) А реврайт сюда не подтянется.

Comment: @dimka3210 В том-то вся и проблема, что почему-то подтягивается!