# Неправильная конструкция mvc?

Tags: php, mvc

Вопрос, вытекающий из предыдущего [вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/276903/php-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-mod_rewrite-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BA%D0%B8)

Возможно, у меня неправильная конструкция MVC?

Все запросы проходят через основной index.php, используется ЧПУ. В htaccess прописано, что все запросы перенаправляются на index.php. index.php передает управление роутеру, который выделяет из строки урл необходимый метод, если метода не существует - класс View выводит на экран: "не найдено". Правильно?

Далее, в папке admin находится свой index.php и свой роутер, который обрабатывает уже не ЧПУ, а простые ссылки вида **/?action=edit&target=main**.

Как же быть? Проходят ли такие "админские" запросы через **основной** index.php или нет? Правильно ли сконструирован сайт? И если правильно, почему я **не могу** поставить пароль на папку admin?

**UPDATE** Более точнее - вход на сайт к примеру www.mysite.

Вход в админку - www.mysite/admin

Comment: на мой взгляд вывод вы сделали достаточно верный, чем 'admin' должен отличаться от остальных контроллеров? Получается, что вы строите 2 приложения, хотя это вроде как не так. Реализуйте авторизацию средствами php (это заодно поможет вам и логировать пользователей, получить нормальный способ ими управлять, а также хранить email, имена и т.д.), добавьте поддержку темплейтов, для того чтобы админка выглядела по другому и в принципе все.

Comment: @zippp, вы представляете, что на хостинге в один клик ставится пароль на папку? У меня не получилось(((. Да, придется делать с помощью php, просто интересно, почему не получается htaccess? Админка создана только для одного человека - админа. И все.

Comment: вы .htaccess куда складываете ? в admin ? ну напишите вы RewriteCond !^/?admin перед RewriteCond !-f

Comment: @eicto, да, прописывал. И не только это. не получается. У вас есть скайп? Я 5й день сижу над проблемой.

Comment: извините, скайп только для работы(за деньги)

Comment: @eicto, хорошо. согласен

Comment: @eicto, deus1725

Comment: @Deus а вы представляете, как себя ощущаешь, когда вроде что-то толковое посоветовал, а не "читай нуб книжку" и тебе отвечают "а вы представляете". Да я отлично представляю, но я вам описал плюсы полноценной авторизации, которая поднимается не за клик, но за час-два с тестами. 
Если вам так хочется все получить отдельно, то представляете, несложно сделать на вашем замечательном хостинге субдомен "admin.domain_name.com" с доступом к общей БД, в настройках указать ему document root отдельный от вашего основного приложения и установить там авторизацию "в один клик" как вам нравится

Answer (score 2):

При чем тут MVC вообще? Советую для начала освоить какой-нибудь популярный MVC фреймворк, например http://kohanaframework.su/, для того чтобы понять как примерно все должно выглядеть и работать.

Comment: @Антон Шаманов Послушай меня, мой друг, не интересуют меня фреймворки,х...ки и т.д. Я любитель "интересного" программирования. И я задал адекватный вопрос. Может быть тебе посоветовать что-нибудь почитать и поучить? Ты давай работай по своей профессии, хорошо?

Comment: Не стоит тыкать незнакомым людям. Что вам не нравится в перенимании чужого удачного опыта?

Comment: @Антон Шаманов, извини(те) за "ты". Сам не ожидал от себя такого. Но такого от вас я точно не ожидал.